# how to generate QR images from url in php

Tags: php, qr-code

how can i generate [QR Images](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_Code) from an URL and display them on a website?

ideally in PHP but any other popular server side language would work too, as long as it is not too complicated to set up.

thanks!

Comment: http://open.visualead.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Google chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/making_charts) and it's QR code output.
NOTE that it has been **deprecated** (see https://developers.google.com/chart/terms).

Sample QR code pointing to https://www.google.com of 300x300 pixels:
[https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&choe=UTF-8](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=http://www.google.com/&choe=UTF-8)

Comment: Link is dead. This one works: http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&choe=UTF-8

Comment: Why would all images have such a huge white padding around it?

Answer (score 3):

http://code.google.com/p/qrforall/ is a PHP class for automatic creation of qr code images.

Comment: Yes there is a PHP Pear class: http://pear.php.net/package/Image_QRCode/docs/latest/Image_QRCode/_Image_QRCode-0.1.0---Image---QRCode.php.html , but I suggest you to use the Google Code qr library.

Answer (score 0):

As Google chart has been deprecated since April 2012, you can use http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/ instead:

> PHP QR Code is open source (LGPL) library for generating QR Code,
>   2-dimensional barcode. Based on libqrencode C library, provides API
>   for creating QR Code barcode images (PNG, JPEG thanks to GD2).
>   **Implemented purely in PHP**, with no external dependencies (except GD2
>   if needed).